# How to show two decimal place in android editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am formatted value in two decimal places: `edAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f", balancePayment));`
in Log.d it show formated value:

```
"Log.d("String format:",String.format("%.2f", balancePayment)); 
D/String format:: 22.00
```

But Edit text shows **"22.0"** What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    String output = formatter.format(balancePayment);
edAmount.setText(output);
```